# React native jest test with expo-constants and extra property

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, expo

I have a react native expo app. I am currently writing tests for said app and there is a problem. I am using app.config.ts to export some variables with the extra property. In my file i am reading the property like so: `let supabaseUrl = Constants.expoConfig.extra.supabaseUrl;`

However I am getting the following error in my test case:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extra')

       9 | import { Database } from "../interfaces/supabase";
      10 |
    > 11 | let supabaseUrl = Constants.expoConfig.extra.supabaseUrl;
         |                                        ^
      12 | if (supabaseUrl === "http://10.0.2.2:54321") {
      13 |   const uri = `http://${Constants.expoConfig?.hostUri
      14 |     ?.split(":")

      at Object.extra (src/supabase/supabase.ts:11:40)
      at Object.require (src/utils/savePost.ts:2:1)
      at Object.require (src/screens/MapScreen/index.tsx:46:1)
      at Object.require (src/screens/MapScreen/MapScreen.test.tsx:9:1)
```

So far, I have tried the following:

I have implemented a solution involving mocking `expo-constants` but the test cases are still failing because of the error.

Here is my mocked implementation. The file path is `tests/mocks/expo-constants.ts`

```js
const expoConstantsMock = {
  expoConfig: {
    extra: {
      supabaseUrl: "https://id.supabase.co",
      anonKey:  "key",
      bucket: "bucket-dev",
    },
  },
};

jest.mock("expo-constants", () => expoConstantsMock);
```

And I added this line in my `package.json` under the jest section:

```json
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^expo-constants$": "<rootDir>/tests/mocks/expo-constants.ts"
    },
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expo constants doesn't have a value(is undefined) when ran in the Jest environment but however it does when running in normal development env.

You need to define the values of the variables required for the unit testing before starting the test.

You can use:

```js
beforeAll(() => {
   // configure expo constants
   Constants.expoConfig = {...};
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working as of Jan 2024. I think it may be related to Contants moving to the 'expo-constants' module

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a workaround? of some sort. I kept my implementation of the mocked `expo-constants` and added the following code for every test suite (directly below the describe method), that used `Constants.expoConfig.extra`:

```js
beforeAll(() => {
    Constants.expoConfig = {
      extra: {
        supabaseUrl: "https://id.supabase.co",
        anonKey: "id",
        bucket: "bucket-dev",
      },
      version: "1.0.0",
      name: "name",
      slug: "slug",
    };
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working as of Jan 2024.